Best way to make borders for a crossword in CSS?
I am trying to create a "crossword" where only two words cross with each other. I would like the squares to be separated between each other by 1px, but a thick, 5 or 10px border around the crossword itself. Here is a quick demonstration of what I would like to do, made with Excel:

For making the grid, I am creating a rectangle of 6x5 blocks, some of them being invisible, and some being visible:
let word_vertical = "GHIEJ";
let junction_vertical = 4;
let word_horizontal = "ABCDEF";
let junction_horizontal = 5;

let number_of_letters_vertical = word_vertical.length;
let number_of_letters_horizontal = word_horizontal.length;
let letter_junction = word_vertical[junction_vertical - 1];

let board = document.getElementById("board");

for (let i = 0; i < number_of_letters_vertical; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "letter-row";

    for (let j = 0; j < number_of_letters_horizontal; j++) {
        let box = document.createElement("div");
        if (i === junction_vertical - 1 || j === junction_horizontal - 1){
            box.className = "letter-box";
            if (j === junction_horizontal - 1) {
                box.innerText = word_vertical[i];
            } else if (i === junction_vertical - 1){
                box.innerText = word_horizontal[j];
            }
        } else {
            box.className = "empty-box";
        }

        row.appendChild(box)
    }

    board.appendChild(row)
}

And here is the CSS:
.letter-row {
    display: flex;
}

.letter-box {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.empty-box {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

Finally the HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="game-page">
    <div id="game-board">
        <div id="board"></div>
    </div>
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>

This turns out to look like this:

As you can see, the borders around are very thin (1px) and the borders between two cells are 2px (1px for each cell contributing). I have tried a few things, including applying directional borders to the empty boxes but that gets complex very fast. Any ideas? Thanks :)

look at drop-shadow filter

@TemaniAfif: I looked into that already, but it would drop the shadows onto the other squares, which I don't want - I would want the shadow to be around the visible squares

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D: Done!

Use drop-shadow filter as @TemaniAfif suggested:


let word_vertical = "GHIEJ";
let junction_vertical = 4;
let word_horizontal = "ABCDEF";
let junction_horizontal = 5;

let number_of_letters_vertical = word_vertical.length;
let number_of_letters_horizontal = word_horizontal.length;
let letter_junction = word_vertical[junction_vertical - 1];

let board = document.getElementById("board");

for (let i = 0; i < number_of_letters_vertical; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "letter-row";

  for (let j = 0; j < number_of_letters_horizontal; j++) {
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    if (i === junction_vertical - 1 || j === junction_horizontal - 1) {
      box.className = "letter-box";
      if (j === junction_horizontal - 1) {
        box.innerText = word_vertical[i];
      } else if (i === junction_vertical - 1) {
        box.innerText = word_horizontal[j];
      }
    } else {
      box.className = "empty-box";
    }

    row.appendChild(box)
  }

  board.appendChild(row)
}
#board {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 0 0) drop-shadow(-5px 0 0) drop-shadow(0 -5px 0) drop-shadow(0 5px 0)
}

.letter-row {
  display: flex;
}

.letter-box {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.empty-box {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<body class="game-page">
  <div id="game-board">
    <div id="board"></div>
  </div>
</body>




It works! Thank you :)
